# Unknown animation name: objectAnimator. Using Nine Old Androids. Still getting error

Tags: android, android-layout, jar, nineoldandroids

I have 2 fragments that I want to swap between using a card flip animation.

Here is one of my animation files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

I have 4 files like this. They are pretty much taken straight from this [Google Demo](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html). I have a minimum sdk of 8, so I am using the highly recommended [Nine Old Androids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) library. However, I am still getting the following error: `Uknown animation name: objectAnimator`. I can import the package for objectAnimator in my java files, so I am pretty certain I have everything configured properly with the JAR file. Earlier I set the `objectAnimator` to `translate` (and changed the attribute values) and it did do an animation, just not the more complicated one I am going for.

Does anyone have any advice on what I might be doing wrong? I am beginning to grasp at straws.

**Edit:** Just in case it helps, here is my flipCard function:

```
public void flipSalesCard(FragmentManager fm) {
        if (salesShowingBack) {
            salesShowingBack = false;
            Fragment smallSSF = new SmallSalesSectionFragment();
            FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction();
            trans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.card_flip_left_in, R.anim.card_flip_left_out);
            trans.replace(R.id.SalesInfoFragment, smallSSF);
            trans.addToBackStack(null);
            trans.commit();
            return;
        }
        salesShowingBack = true;

        Fragment expandedSSF = new ExpandedSalesSectionFragment();
        FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction();
        trans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.card_flip_right_in, R.anim.card_flip_right_out);
        trans.replace(R.id.SalesInfoFragment, expandedSSF);
        trans.addToBackStack(null);
        trans.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nine Old doesn't work with fragment https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/issues/43

There's another library for that https://github.com/kedzie/Support_v4_NineOldAndroids
but be careful of the caveats as "View animations will no longer work"

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to do it programatically?

My answer to: [How to animate a slide in notification view that pushes the content view down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098083/how-to-animate-a-slide-in-notification-view-that-pushes-the-content-view-down/19098369#19098369) is an example of this.

Also what happens if you move one of xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" up into the set declaration and remove the other.

Comment: If I move that, the autocomplete does not recognize `objectAnimator`. Also, the demo from Nine Old Androids had it there, so I copied them. I could look into doing it programatically, but was hoping to do it like the android example. I need the card flip, not just slide in.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours on the same problem and came up dry. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694612/2926226) provided an alternate technique (that doesn't need NineOldAndroid) for implementing the flip rotation which worked out very nicely.