# Flip card transition between two activities Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the `Flip card` transition effect between two activities in my app by taking help from : 
 http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/.
But I couldn't understand what are`ActivitySwitcher.java` and `Roatate3dAnimation.java` in the above mentioned site. I have two activities in my app between whom I want to show this transition effect. They are `MainActivity.java` and `About_us.java`.
Please explain the code with reference to my activities. I also searched on http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html but in vain as it not for activities.
Thanks!

Comment: why don't you do it with the Fragments as like in the last link in developer web site. It's easier.

Comment: @osayilganThanks for your quick reply! But you got my question wrong.
What I want to do is display a transition effect between two activities.

Comment: What didn't you understand in those classes ? It's quite clear. You just implement the Code respectively as Activity1 and Activity2 as your MainActivity and About_us activities.

Comment: @osayilgan All what I didn't understand is the use and implementation of `ActivitySwitcher.java` and `Rotate3dAnimation.java`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Card Flip Animation between Activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309931/card-flip-animation-between-activities)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Disclaimer: This is not a an actual 3D Animation Flip.  This merely imitates it, though some don't agree.  Give it a try and if you like it, great!  If you don't, my apologies.**

In my early days of learning to code, I was having issues implementing a proper 3D Animation flip, so I went with this, it simulated it enough to satisfy my needs, but to each her/his own.  To do what I did, first make sure that you have a folder called anim under your res folder for your project.  Then you will need to create two xml files (I have mine called from_middle and to_middle).  Below is the code for each of those:

from_middle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%" 
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotY="50%"         
    android:duration="500" />
```

to_middle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%" 
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotY="50%"        
    android:duration="500" />
```

After those are created, all you need is one line of code to run this animation, which you should be placed after you start your next activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);
```

Done!  Now run it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts!! I'll definitely try it and let you know the results.

Comment: Weird.. it does for me.  What happened?  Please post your code so I can take a closer look

Comment: I'm really sorry man! It works!!!!! It was an error from my side but now it works like a charm! Thanks a lot and sincere apologies for earlier.

Comment: Sweet!  Not a problem, glad I could help!  It took me forever to find help on that, so I'm more than happy to pass it on.  Please accept the answer if you would be so inclined :)

Comment: BTW did you write the code yourself or found it out somewhere?

Comment: I found it elsewhere, I am currently looking for the source to give them a shout out!

Comment: This is not a flip-card animation. Flip card animations are 3 dimensional, and this is a simply a trick using 2 dimensional scale animations. It by no means gives the same effect. While some people may think it's "close enough", i definitely don't agree.

Comment: Hi,Where exactly I need to place the overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle); ?

If I am calling Activity2 from Activity1 onclick of a button,
then should I apply the same like,

Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent); overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);

Because placing it here does not work for me.

Comment: Please edit your answer warning users that this is not a flip card animation.

Answer (score 2):

Based on user1672053's answer, you need to add a start offset to the `from_middle.xml` resource which is equal to the duration of the `to_middle.xml` animation resource.