# Name of the UI used in the App present in playstore and how to achieve the same?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view, android-design-library

I am a newbee in Android development, I just want to know if anyone can tell me what the `UI or View` is which is used in the `News In Short` app (present in the `play store`). Can anyone provide a link (tutorial) where I can learn to implement it?

The link to the app below.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nis.app&hl=en

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appear they have used Custom UI/View.

I think they have done some thing like This:

1. Storing News in List<NewsVO>
2. Then might be they have used to 3 Fragments(or Activity).

News 1 will come on Fragment 1

News 2 on Fragment 2

News 3 on Fragment 3.

and then reusing this 3 Fragments.

Finger Movement:

1. Top to Down: Show Previous News/ Fragment
2. Down to Top: Show Next News/Fragment
3. Left to Right: Show WebView Activity(Move to WebView Activity with Animation)

Now on Fragments they added animations.

Comment: Well can the same be achived using Swipe Gestured?

Comment: yes swipe gesture can be used for finger movement by Animation will be used between  Fragment/Activity Transition...

Comment: Could you provide any tutorial link for the same where it could be achieve?

Comment: For Swipe Gesture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures
For Animation while moving from one activity to another:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958975/flip-card-transition-between-two-activities-android
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-animation-while-switching.html

Comment: Thanks mate. could you please edit your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: To Save your effort what you can do: 1. Download the Apk from "http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/" 2. Decompile the apk from http://www.decompileandroid.com/   . Just study the Code :)