# How to Flip Animation like card-flip between two activities?

Tags: java, android

I want to flip the one activity to other activity like card view. Please tell me
I am also using roate3danimation and Flip3dAnimation but these are flip the views.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958975/flip-card-transition-between-two-activities-android

Comment: I want  to do 3d flip animation?

Comment: Add some code that you have written so far

Comment: I am using this [link] http://blog.robert-heim.de/career/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this blogpost to flip activities http://blog.robert-heim.de/career/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/

Comment: thanks but I tried this when flip the activity container shown same on other side

Comment: I want to other side the container takes of new activity.

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini i used same tutorial worked fine for me you must be doing something wrong there need your code to figure out what is wrong

Comment: I will try Again tell you later friend