# Flip animation while moving from one activity to another in android

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, flip

Like in google api

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/animation/cardflip.html

instead of doing with two fragment how to do with two activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309931/card-flip-animation-between-activities

Comment: `android:windowEnterTransition` maybe this can help you. This can be added in styles.xml

Answer (score -1):

Take the same xml in the link you've posted and implement it uses this approach

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145226/2435402

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.flip_right, R.anim.flip_left);
```